I can't upload a local file to Wt
The problem is that in Wt I cannot download a local file from my computer, I can download a file from the Internet, please help me how to solve this problem...
Here is the source code:
#include "headers.h"

std::string readFileToString(const std::string &filePath) {
  std::ifstream file(filePath);
  std::stringstream buffer;
  buffer << file.rdbuf();
  return buffer.str();
}

class Application : public Wt::WApplication
{
public:
  Application(const Wt::WEnvironment &env);
  
private:
  bool isClicked = true;
};

Application::Application(const Wt::WEnvironment &env) : WApplication(env)
{
  this->setTitle("App");

  this->doJavaScript(std::async(std::launch::async | std::launch::deferred, 
    readFileToString,
    "D:/web/script.js"
  ).get());

  auto image = this->root()->addWidget(std::make_unique<Wt::WImage>(""));
  image->setAttributeValue("src", "icons/image.png");
  image->setAttributeValue("alt", "image");

  image->setId("main-image");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
  return Wt::WRun(argc, argv, [](const Wt::WEnvironment &env) {
    auto app = std::make_unique<Application>(env);
    return app;
  });
}

It doesn't load icons/image
image.png:1
Here's what it says in the browser:
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/icons/image.png 404 (Not Found)

One way to deploy static assets is using the docroot option to specify the location of the static assets:
./myApp --docroot="/path/to/static/asssets;/icons" ...

